# How to remove "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0" from http response header on App Service Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created two asp.net + MVC applications and deployed one to Azure App Service web app and other into an app service web application created in a ASE (Application Service Environment).

When providing special characters in the URL the response header consists of "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0". I have done the below changes in the application but the issue still persists.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true"/>
</security>

protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the default header. You could create a http module to do it. Code below is for your reference.

```
public class RemoveDefaultHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += Context_PreSendRequestHeaders;
    }

    private void Context_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove the header you wanted
        (sender as HttpApplication).Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        (sender as HttpApplication).Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    }
}
```

You also need to register this module in web.config. Don't forget to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests property to true which will make this module works for static resources.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="RemoveDefaultHeaderModule" type="TestServerHeader.RemoveDefaultHeaderModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable inputs. I have tried your suggestion but i still see 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0' in the response when i provide special characters in URL

Comment: What do you mean of special characters? Could you provide a sample URL for test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0 and I got it working by running powershell(as admin) and did the following:

```
PS > cd IIS:\
PS > Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "system.webServer/security/requestFiltering" -name "removeServerHeader" -value "True"
```

Combined with this in the web.config:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
</security>
```

As a reference, I red this [blog post](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/iis10.html).

However, when I edit the web.config for any reason, I must rerun the script in order to remove the server header again... Or it seems to be there for a short time after updating the web.config...

Hope this help!